# Can the Cult Leader recruit Lycans and Maple Wolves?

Tags: werewolv.es

Can the Cult Leader recruit Lycans, or is their form of lycanthropy too mild for that? Some have said that only the Sanguine Horn can make players able to be recruited.

Answer (score 1):

Lycanthropy and being a lycan is not the same, so Lycans can't be recruited by the Cult without a Sanguine horn.